# Play Framework routing error that I can't fix

Tags: java, playframework

I am building my first controller with the Play Framework. I'm receiving the error:

```
Compilation error value getAll is not a member of controllers.api.protocol.Period
```

My routes.conf file looks like:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET        /                                     controllers.Application.index()

GET        /api/protocol/period                  controllers.api.protocol.Period.getAll()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

and "controllers/api/protocol/Period.java" looks like:

```
package controllers.api.protocol;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import java.util.List;
import play.mvc.*;
import static play.libs.Json.toJson;

public class Period extends Controller {

    public static Result getAll() {
        List<model.Protocol.Period> periods = new Model.Finder<Integer.class>(model.Protocol.Period.class).all();
        return ok(toJson(periods));
    }
}
```

I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's great, and welcome. :)

Remove `static` from `public static Result getAll()` and you're sorted.

Comment: I had the same problem, but why you have to remove static when in all the examples I found instead is this?
has anything changed in the latest version?

Comment: @pagurix: compare https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActions and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActions As you can see, in Play 2.4 you are no longer required to use static for your controllers' methods. Related: Play 2.4 introduced DI

Comment: Yes, what @Anton said, the examples you saw were probably 2.3 based, not 2.4 based, as 2.4 is still relatively new.